# No puedo insertar/actualizar datos en el detalle de una Transacción GeneXus

Tags: android, genexusxev3

Tengo tres transacciones con la siguiente estrucutura

```
Cliente
{
    ClienteId*
    ClienteNombre
}

Articulo
{
    ArticuloId*
    ArticuloNombre
    ArticuloPrecio
}

Factura
{
    FacturaId*
    FacturaFecha
    ClienteId
    {
    ArticuloId*
    ArticuloNombre
    ArticuloPrecio
    FacturaArticuloCant
    FacturaArticuloImporteLinea (ArticuloCantFactura*ArticuloCant)
    }
}
FacturaImporte ( sum(FacturaArticuloImporteLinea) )
```

Estoy usando:

- SQL Server 2012
- C#
- GenexusX Ev3U1
- Generando para Android

Insertar / Actualizar en transacciones Cliente y Factura anda bien.
Insertar / Actualizar en factura de transacción solo funciona en la sección de encabezado. Cuando se cambia a la sección de detalles, la aplicación muestra el indicador de progreso pero nunca muestra el grid para insertar o editar datos.

Qué puede estar pasando que la app no permite ingresar o actualizar datos en la sección detalle?

Gracias